# What is the difference between "void function()" and "void *function()"?

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly

I knew the `void *function()` is the pointer which point to a function but I don't know how different they work and when we use `void *function()`?
I did some research in assembly to compare how they work behind the scene and look like they are same.
Here is the c++ code:

```
void *bar(){
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
}

void foo(){
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

int main(void){
        foo();
        bar();

        return 0;
}
```

And this is assembly instruction I receive from objdump

```
void *bar(){
  400846:       55                      push   %rbp
  400847:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
  40084a:       be 84 09 40 00          mov    $0x400984,%esi
  40084f:       bf 60 10 60 00          mov    $0x601060,%edi
  400854:       e8 b7 fe ff ff          callq  400710 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
  400859:       be 30 07 40 00          mov    $0x400730,%esi
  40085e:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400861:       e8 ba fe ff ff          callq  400720 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
}
  400866:       90                      nop
  400867:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400868:       c3                      retq   

0000000000400869 <_Z3foov>:

void foo(){
  400869:       55                      push   %rbp
  40086a:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
  40086d:       be 88 09 40 00          mov    $0x400988,%esi
  400872:       bf 60 10 60 00          mov    $0x601060,%edi
  400877:       e8 94 fe ff ff          callq  400710 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
  40087c:       be 30 07 40 00          mov    $0x400730,%esi
  400881:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400884:       e8 97 fe ff ff          callq  400720 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
}
  400889:       90                      nop
  40088a:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  40088b:       c3                      retq   

000000000040088c <main>:

int main(void){
  40088c:       55                      push   %rbp
  40088d:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
        foo();
  400890:       e8 d4 ff ff ff          callq  400869 <_Z3foov>
        bar();
  400895:       e8 ac ff ff ff          callq  400846 <_Z3barv>

        return 0;
  40089a:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  40089f:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4008a0:       c3                      retq
```

Comment: One function is declared to return a "generic" pointer. The other function is declared to not return anything.'

Comment: Have you checked for warnings from the compiler? The first function doesn't look quite right.

Comment: `bar` returns a `void` pointer while `foo` returns nothing. If that's not a difference enough by itself then you need to read a good book before continuing.

Comment: Oh and if you declare a function to return something, you *must* return something or you have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You should get something like `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: @E_net4 Maybe I doesn't give the compiler enough option while compile because compiler doesn't give me any warnings.

Comment: @DuyVu -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic for any gcc/clang compiler chain.

Comment: You might need to include the necessary flags for that. And they depend on the compiler that you used.

Comment: Your tests make no sense since you return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the answers you had in the comments already, the difference is the type returned

```
void foo() { ... }
```

Is a function that returns nothing, while

```
void *bar() { ... }
void* bar() { ... } // Identical
```

Return a `void` pointer. Swapping the space position before or after the `*` makes no difference here, but it may make it clearer what the return type is. And of course make sure to actually return something in the case of this `bar` function, or you will have a compiler warning at least, and undefined behavior.

So basically this is just two slightly different meanings of the keyword `void` to remember. If you are not familiar with C++ there a good amount of accessible book that can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

`void` does not return anything.

`void*` returns a pointer to something of which the type is not known. It is something you normally don't want to return, but instead the type of the object you want to return to guarantee type safety. The only place where you want to use `void*` as return type is when dealing with raw memory. For example `malloc` and `new` return a `void*` because their return value has no type (that is up to the caller of `malloc` or `new`).

Your `bar` function is wrong, because the return type is a `void*`, but you do not return anything.

Answer (score -1):

void does not return anything

void * returns pointer

Do not waste your time reading disassembly listings - properly learn C instead

***Do not ignore warnings!!!!!!***

```
void *bar(){
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
}
```

You have got same warnings? Haven't you?

> I knew the void *function() is the pointer which point to a function

Now you do not know. It is not the function pointer. Learn C or C++ first.