# Too many arguments to function ‘pthread_create’

Tags: c, multithreading, syntax, pthreads

As the title im trying to figure out how I can pass in all my start routine functions arguments into my pthread, but I am not having great luck with it

```
pthread_create(firstThread,NULL,sort,first,first_size);
```

I'm trying to pass in my sort function that takes two args, array Pointer, and array size, but I am not familiar with the syntax for passing in several arguments into a thread, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use a `struct` and put all your arguments in it and then pass it to the thread function.

Comment: That is, pass *a pointer to the struct* via the fourth (and last) argument to `pthread_create`.  It does not work to pass the struct itself by value.

Comment: can anyone explain to me how a struct is created, as i have never done somthing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using multiple arguments with pthread_create

You have to set all your arguments in a struct, see the below working example:

*pthread_arg.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define _DEBUG 1

typedef struct arg {
    int *array;
    int len;
}   t_arg;

void *sort(void *ptr);


int main(void) {
    pthread_t firstThread;

    int first[5] = {3,5,19,6,1};
    int first_size = 5;
    t_arg arg = {.array = first, .len = first_size}; // assign your variable to the variable arg which is a t_arg struct
    pthread_create( &firstThread, NULL, &sort, &arg); // give the struct address to pthread_create
    pthread_join(firstThread, NULL);
}

void *sort(void *ptr) {
    t_arg *arg = ptr; // assign the ptr to arg; 
    int n = arg->len; // now you can work with your function
    int *a = arg->array;

    int i, tmp, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > tmp) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            --j;
        }
        a[j + 1] = tmp;
    }
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    #endif
    return (void *)1; // to compile with -Wall -Wextra -Werror
}
```

Compile with

```
gcc -O3 pthread_arg.c -lpthread && ./a.out
```

edit: you have to change

```c
void sort(void *arg)
```

to

```c
void *sort2(void *arg)
```

As a function returning a void pointer is different from a void function.

And remove the cast for `struct sorting *s = (struct sorting)arg;` => `struct sorting *s = arg;`, there is no need for it.

Comment: on the struct construction what is the purpose of  t_arg; also  on the .array i can replace that with a pointer to a array and it will work the same correct? or are there other things to take into account

Comment: The typedef t_arg allow you to avoid writing struct arg each time you want to declare your structure, which is quite lengthy. You can replace with a ptr to an array but you will need to have it malloced beforehand

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I worked a little bit on it, im having issues but have successfully created a structure and a function that sorts everything properly, but i believe im running the wrong parameters, as i see in your above code, instead of (void *ptr); i passed the structure into it, and of course im now running into the error that my function is incompatible with the Pthread_create(firstThread,NULL,sorting,firstsort); error firstsort is type is incompatible  void sort(struct sorting a), // my version, ive tried running a void like you did, but i just kept getting segmentation vaults

Comment: Pthread needs to call a function that take void *ptr as argument, you cannot have any other type of argument. The rational was to allow developers to pass any type of variable through a ptr (with a struct behind) and avoid variadic arguments.

Comment: Share a code snippet (online) and I will take a look

Comment: i updated the question containing what i got for this currently

Comment: nvm i think i resolved everything! your example helped @antonin GAVREL

Comment: see my edit, explaining what was not working, and read https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859521/3161139

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_create` takes a single argument to be passed to thread function, and that single argument has to be a pointer.

There are only two major ways to pass something to thread function:

- Pass an object which fits into `void*` and than cast;
- Or, create an object on the heap (using `malloc`) and than pass address to this newly created object to thread function. In this case, you'd have to make sure thread function `free`s the memory after using the argument.
- A variation of previous option would be passing a pointer to an object globally available (say, global variable), but this usually is not an acceptable option.
- Another variation is to pass an address to the object defined locally in the body of the calling function, but this is seldom useful beyond school examples, as it is is impossible to achieve parallel execution in this manner (thread will have to be joined before object leaves calling scope).

In your case, it could look like following:

```
typedef struct {
    int* arrayPtr;
    size_t arraySize;
} ThreadedSortArgs;

void threadedSort(void* voidArg) {
   ThreadedSortArgs* arg = voidArg;
   // Work with args from arg->arrayPtr, arg->arraySize
   free(arg);
}

// call it somewhere
ThreadedSortArgs* args = malloc(sizeof(ThreadedSortArgs));
pthread_create(firstThread, NULL, threadedSort, args);
// ...
```

Comment: 'but this is seldom useful beyond school examples' well, if the calling function never returns, [eg. 
while(true){something} loop after creating/initializing stack objects] there is no problem.  That is a pattern that I use often as app-lifetime threads.  As for join - best avoided together:((